# In a list program, print statements are not concatenating properly as float

Tags: python

The below is my code, but I can't get the last few lines to print. I've tried rearranging them, switching from string to float, etc. I don't know if this is just a glitch or a concatenation problem. If so, how would I make the last few lines print with float?

```
N = []
C= []
Holiday = []
totC = 0
name = input("enter name").upper()
while name != "XXX":
    cost = int(input("enter amount to spend >0 and <=10"))
    while cost <=0 or cost >10:
        print("invalid cost")
        cost = int(input("enter amount to spend >0 and <=10"))
    gift = name + " " + str(cost)
    N.append(name)
    C.append(cost)
    Holiday.append(gift)
    totC = totC + cost
    name = input("enter name").upper()

print(Holiday)
print(N)
print(C)
print(totC)
print("Total cost is "  + totC)
print("Average cost is" + av)
print("Number of names is " + len(N))
print("Number of costs is " + len(C))
```

Comment: What input are you providing? And what output is generated for it?

Comment: You can use `str(123)` to change numbers to strings so they can be concatenated with other strings.

Comment: What problems are you encountering? If you get an error, then post the full error message. If you get wrong result, then post the result you get and the result you expect.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that provides a value for `av`.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about casting all those values to strings. You don't need to do that. Instead, write your `print` statements like:

```
print("Total cost is", totC)
print("Average cost is", av)
print("Number of names is", len(N))
print("Number of costs is", len(C))
```

Alternatively, if you're using Python 3.6 or newer, you can use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) like:

```
print(f"Total cost is {totC}")
print(f"Average cost is {av}")
print(f"Number of names is {len(N)}")
print(f"Number of costs is {len(C)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely have to convert the floats and integers to strings using the `str` function.

For example, `print("Number of costs is " + len(C))` would become `print("Number of costs is " + str(len(C)))` and `print("Total cost is "  + totC)` would become `print("Total cost is "  + str(totC))`

The print statements should look like this.

```
print("Total cost is "  + str(totC))
print("Average cost is" + str(av))
print("Number of names is " + str(len(N)))
print("Number of costs is " + str(len(C)))
```

One thing I noticed is that you don't have a variable called `av`, so trying to print it would not work. If you're trying to print the average costs, then you can do `sum(C)/len(C)`. So, you can either add `av = sum(C)/len(C)` right before the print statements, or you can integrate into the print statement, like this:

```
print("Average cost is" + str(sum(C)/len(C)))
```

Comment: No problem! @Julia

Answer (score 0):

Use `str`:

```py
print("Total cost is "  + str(totC))
print("Average cost is" + str(av))
print("Number of names is " + str(len(N)))
print("Number of costs is " + str(len(C)))
```

You might be confusing concatenation with "addition" of strings and integers.

Comment: No worries @Julia!